# Foreach for an array

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>  string(1) "3"
    [1]=>  string(3) "488"
    [2]=>  string(3) "177"
}
```

I want to have a `foreach` for its values, which returns the number in the array.
How can I do that?

Comment: @NullUserException: I guess he meant to write “its”.

Comment: What result do you expect in this case?

Comment: I don't get the question. If you know what  [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) does (Which isn't that hard), you shouldn't be asking this.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334016/4751173).

Answer (score 4):

I sure hope I understood your question..

```
foreach ($yourArray as $value)
{
    // ...
}

// OR

foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can extract values and keys with [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PHP doc

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

The code would look like

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```

You can find more about foreach [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score -1):

By numbers do you mean the strings?

```
var_dump(array_values($your_array));
```